# Phantomjs failing to load webpage using angularjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using capserjs to test my application. But the problem is, the body doesnt load i.e., there are no tags/elements within the rendered `<ng-Outlet>` tag. Any amount of wait time is not helping. Not sure what is causing the issue. Any pointer would help.

```
casper.start('URL', function() {
    this.viewport(1300,750);
    this.waitForSelector('#user',function(){
        this.sendKeys('#user','username');
        this.sendKeys('#passwd','passwd');
        this.echo('All values are entered');
    },function(){},20000);
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
    document.getElementById('sign_in').click();
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.wait(5000);
    this.captureSelector('InitialPage_1.png','body');
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
    this.waitForText("Trash",function(){
        this.captureSelector('InitialPage_2','html');
    }, function(){
        this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
        this.echo(this.getHTML());
    }, 15000);
});

casper.run();
```

NOTE: When I run the same page with chrome or FF driver using selenium, it is working fine.

Comment: You've added some (unindented!!!) code here. At which point do you have a problem? `casper.wait` is asynchronous, but `casper.captureSelector` is synchronous, so `casper.captureSelector` will always be executed *before* `casper.wait` regardless how much you try to wait.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. If you note, i have given 15000 time delay for the text 'Trash' to appear on the page. But 'InitialPage_2' never prints out. I analyzed the problem little further... I am using phantomcss and phantomxhr over this. So what i noted is, the API calls are never made and hence the body if empty. The execution stop abruptly at some point. Is there any way to debug why these calls are not being made??

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `casper.captureSelector` if you're trying to render the whole page (`html` and `body` both represent the visible page). Try `casper.capture`. The other question is why are you using `casper.thenEvaluate(function(){ document.getElementById('sign_in').click(); });` and not simply `casper.thenClick('#sign_in')`?

Comment: As you have rightly said, the code which is posted is really unintended code here !!. I used `casper.capture` as you have suggested but the result is same. I have a blank page with no contents. For the the second question, my first try was `casper.click('#sign_in')` and it simply refused to work !!! So i went with Jquery approach. But my real question is, is there a reason why API calls wont be invoked in phantomjs, for a project developed with angular ?

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Actually error while running only via Phantoms JS.  Error: Can't find variable: Map
RouteRegistry@https://DomainName/libs/angular/router/angular1/angul
ar_1_router.js:2173:30
routerFactory@https://DomainName/libs/angular/router/angular1/angul
ar_1_router.js:3071:35
invoke@https://DomainName/libs/angular/angular-lib/angular.min.js:4
1:300

Comment: Using phantomjs version 2.1.1. I have tried to install _harmony-collections_ via npm but still facing same issue.

Comment: Also i noted your answer on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629774/does-phantomjs-support-es6-for-serving-angularjs-app-to-crawlers-and-bots) to be highly useful. My question thus becomes, is there a workaround for this yet? Or should we move to Slimerjs?

Comment: You can certainly move to Slimer.js, but then it won't be headless anymore. If you're running Linux, then you can use xvfb to make it headless. After you've done that, you should really check if you can move to Selenium, because then you have access to many more browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. My goal is Visual regression testing using phantomcss and phantomxhr. I have successfully achieved slimer+phantomcss to work together. But bringing in phantomxhr into the mix seems to a problem. Will find a way, hopefully..

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb, when requesting a new resource (e.g. submitting a form) always use a wait**For** and the inside that function perform a capture selector

```
casper.start('URL', function() {
 ...
});


casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
  document.getElementById('sign_in').click();
});

casper.wait(5000, function(){
  this.captureSelector('InitialPage_1.png','body');
  this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```

Note there are several issues here, not sure why you are using evaluate and send keys, as there are other alternatives, but hey ho

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Rippo . I am new to CapserJS but worked with Selenium. So hope you understand the attachment towards _SendKeys_. Code is clumsy but that is okay for my purpose. Real question, will there be any issues while using phantomjs to render angularjs projects? Any suggestion might help.

Comment: No spa's work fine **BUT** remember things take a little time to get to the dom so you may need to use casper.wait**FOR** more